# Parse XML with quoted attributes

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm using a 3rd party XML parser (not my decision) and found it does something bad. Here is the inner part of an XML tag:

```
"Date=""2014-01-01"" Amounts=""100717.72 100717.72 100717.72 100717.72"""
```

To parse the attributes, the code does a `.split` on spaces, ignoring the quotes. This works fine as long as there's no strings with spaces, but here we are. It returns proper Date=2014-01-01 and semi-proper Amounts=100717.72, but then four more entries of just the numbers.

I have the C# code for the parser, and thought about replacing the spaces-inside-quotes with some other character, splitting, and the changing them back. But then I thought I should ask here first.

Is there a way to parse this text into two entries properly?

**UPDATE:** original XML follows (typed in from another computer, forgive me!)

```
<DetailAmounts Date="2014-01-01" Amounts="100717.72 100717.72 100717.72 100717.72" />
```

Comment: So this is the attribute given as is which you have no control over? Is the double double-quote always present? Do you also need every number?

Comment: The attribute comes from a text file generated by a 3rd party server - no access there. The double-quote is NOT in the original file, it appears to be something that happens in the debugger output perhaps? I do need every number, I should get two items back, the second one being the entire Amounts= string

Comment: It is valid xml. The parser you (have to?) use is just bad. Why not use normal xml features of .net (like xmlserializer)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the data:

```
public class DetailAmounts
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Amounts { get; set; }
}

// ...

var xml = "<DetailAmounts Date=\"2014-01-01\" Amounts=\"100717.72 100717.72 100717.72 100717.72\" />";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DetailAmounts));
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var detailAmounts = (DetailAmounts)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Or, you can use `XElement` to parse each individual values:

```
var xml = "<DetailAmounts Date=\"2014-01-01\" Amounts=\"100717.72 100717.72 100717.72 100717.72\" />";
var element = XElement.Parse(xml);
var detailAmounts = new
{
    Date = (DateTime)element.Attribute("Date"),
    Amounts = element.Attribute("Amounts").Value.Split(' ')
        .Select(x => decimal.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .ToArray()
};
```